# SELECT from "vertical" table and display on "horizontal" table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table in my db:

> ```
> table
> ----------
> cityID
> value 
> parameterID
> ```

The table looks like this:

> ```
> cityID     value      parameterID
> 500        30         1
> 500        60         2
> 500        7          3
> 600        25         1
> 600        50         2
> 600        6          3   
> ....       ...        .....
> ```

where 1,2, 3 stands for temperature, humidity and cm of rain.

I need to display this data this way:

> ```
>    city       temp        humidity       rain
>    500        30           60            7
>    600        25           50            6
> ```

What I did was this (after SELECT * FROM table):

```
 /*retrieve all values and put them in loooong arrays */

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      
$selectcityID_array[] = (isset ($row['cityID']) ? $row['cityID'] : "");
$selectparameterID_array[] = (isset ($row['parameterID']) ? $row['parameterID'] : "");  
$selectvalue_array[] = (isset ($row['value']) ? $row['value'] : "");    
 }
/* remove doubles from cities and parameters*/
$selectcityID_array_unique = array_values (array_unique($selectcityID_array) );
$selectparameterID_array_unique = array_values (array_unique($selectparameterID_array) );

/*chunk the values do that I have an "horizontal" array for every city*/
$value_array_chunked = array_chunk($selectvalue_array, count($selectparameterID_array_unique));


for ($i=0; $i < count($selectcityID _array_unique); ++$i){ /*for every city*/
   for ($i_content=0; $i_content < count($selectparameterID_array_unique); ++$i_content){ /*and for every parameter*/
        echo $ value_array_chunked[$i][$i_content];
        echo ' ';
     }

     echo '<br>';

}
```

It works, but is this the only (and best) way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use *conditional aggregation* to get the expected result set:

```sql
SELECT cityID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN parameterID = 1 THEN value END) AS temp,
       MAX(CASE WHEN parameterID = 2 THEN value END) AS humidity,
       MAX(CASE WHEN parameterID = 3 THEN value END) AS rain
FROM mytable
GROUP BY cityID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e0d4/1)

Answer (score 1):

You may also join the table to itself:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
tablea.cityID AS city,
ttemp.value AS temp,
thumid.value AS humidity,
train.value AS rain
FROM tablea
LEFT JOIN tablea AS ttemp
ON ttemp.cityID = tablea.cityID AND ttemp.parameterID = 1
LEFT JOIN tablea AS thumid
ON thumid.cityID = tablea.cityID AND thumid.parameterID = 2
LEFT JOIN tablea AS train
ON train.cityID = tablea.cityID AND train.parameterID = 3
```

below is my testing:

[image: tried in my dev envt]

Comment: Thanks Ceeee! I only don't understand why I need the the last line DELETE...

Comment: that's for my testing only, dont mind the insert and delete :D just checked if the query works even if one city do not have ony of temp/humidity/rain